# Can't update fusion table?

Tags: javascript

How to update fusion table rows dynamically using javascript.
I tried below code to update Fusion Table Rows, But I can't update.

```
function auth() {
    var config = {
        'client_id': '967151873725-c2j3knppcmpb3413c7vrnt058e42cqpu.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables',
        'immediate': false
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
        console.log('login complete');
        console.log(gapi.auth.getToken());
    });
}

function update_row() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyC2JH9H1jkG_73Oq2LJapPE9TLxYMjG1II');

    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v2', function () {
        var query = "UPDATE 19fAu4GLLQ6eJC1hB7ZdTAkH34pqM-NHv4knFeKfO SET col0 = 'test' WHERE ROWID='1'";

        gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: query }).execute(function (response) { console.log(response); });
    });
}
```

In my fusion table I have three columns like : StudentId, StudentName,StudentAddress. I would likes to update fusion table based on studentId. How to update the particular rows in fusion table.

Any idea?

Comment: Solution Founded :Step 1: First we must get ROWID. to get rowid follow below query var selectQry = "SELECT ROWID FROM 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o WHERE Number = '1'";

Comment: Step 2: gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: selectQry }).execute(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var getRowID = response["rows"][0][0];

                                        var updateQry = "UPDATE 1ATc4raFfvVSJriqgIS2qBHE5GQY4wioDA13LrQ5o SET col2 = 'India', col3='2015' WHERE ROWID = '" + getRowID + "'";
                    gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sql({ sql: updateQry }).execute(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                });